# Two colors (or more) of page, for beginning chapter

Tags: color, backgrounds

I'm trying to make the first page of each chapter in two colors according https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/236952/14423. This works well for the table of contents, but does not work well for the first page of each chapter, as you can see:

Main:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,showtrims,draft,11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\amount}{4in}   %%<---- adjust


\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \fill[green] ([yshift=-\amount]current page.north west) rectangle (current page.north east);
  \fill[yellow] (current page.south west) rectangle ([yshift=-\amount]current page.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\tableofcontents

\include{intro}

\mainmatter

\include{cap1}
\include{cap2}

\backmatter

\include{app}

\end{document}
```

intro.tex :

```
\chapter{Introducci\'on}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \fill[green] ([yshift=-\amount]current page.north west) rectangle (current page.north east);
  \fill[yellow] (current page.south west) rectangle ([yshift=-\amount]current page.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\lipsum[1-5]
```

cap1.tex :

```
\chapter{Cap\'itulo Uno}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \fill[green] ([yshift=-\amount]current page.north west) rectangle (current page.north east);
  \fill[yellow] (current page.south west) rectangle ([yshift=-\amount]current page.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\lipsum[1-5]
```

cap2.tex and app.tex have no lines. Obviously something I'm doing wrong. What is it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I almost got blind by your choice of colors. :-(

Comment: hahahaha is my fault, I just copy a code from the link above ...

Answer (score 1):

The following MWE will do:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,showtrims,draft,11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{everypage}

\newcommand{\amount}{4in}   %%<---- adjust

\makeatletter
\let\oldchapterheadstart\chapterheadstart
\def\chapterheadstart#1{%
  \AddThispageHook{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
      \fill[green] ([yshift=-\amount]current page.north west) rectangle (current page.north east);
      \fill[yellow] (current page.south west) rectangle ([yshift=-\amount]current page.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }%
  \oldchapterheadstart{#1}%  \vspace*{50\p@}%
}

\makeatother



\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\include{intro}

\mainmatter

%\include{cap1}
\chapter{Introducci\'on}

\lipsum[1-5]

%\include{cap2}
\chapter{Cap\'itulo Uno}

\lipsum[1-5]

\backmatter

\include{app}

\end{document}
```

I have added the content of `tikzpicture` inside `\AddThisPageHook{}`, which is now inserted inside the macro `\chapterheadstart{}`. This will now add color layer to all the chapters including unnumbered.

Comment: I was watching with `everypage` package and its commands, although I could not solve it. Thank you.

Comment: Well, trying with your code I get five warnings message ...

Answer (score 1):

In your MWE the `tikzpicture` is inserted when the chapter title was already printed. So it overlays the chapter title.

I would suggest to define an own page style `chapterfirstpage` based on page style `plain`.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,showtrims,draft,11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}

\aliaspagestyle{chapter}{chapterfirstpage}

\copypagestyle{chapterfirstpage}{plain}
  \makeevenhead{chapterfirstpage}{}{\chapterpagebackground}{}
  \makeoddhead{chapterfirstpage}{}{\chapterpagebackground}{}

\newcommand*\chapterpagebackground{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \fill[topcolor] ([yshift=-\amount]current page.north west) rectangle (current page.north east);
  \fill[bottomcolor] (current page.south west) rectangle ([yshift=-\amount]current page.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\amount}{\if@mainmatter 4in\else 3.5in\fi}   %%<---- adjust
\makeatother
\colorlet{topcolor}{green}
\colorlet{bottomcolor}{yellow}

\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument

\mainmatter
\blinddocument
\blinddocument

\backmatter
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Run twice to get

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I could see warnings when compiling, but did not know how to solve.

Comment: Well, trying with your code I get five warnings message ...

Comment: In the second run I do not get any warning if I use an uptodate MiKTeX or an uptodate TL 2016.

Comment: I'm updating my LaTeX version ...